# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'

Tags: python, module, attributes

The problem is on giving a new random number for user to guess it. It displays an error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'

My code is right here:

```
import random
print "Try to find the number I have on my mind in once !! " 
print "Everytime you are wrong the number will change !! " 
guess = 0 
energy = True 
while energy == True:
    random = random.randint(1,100)
    guess = input("What's the number ?? : ")
    if guess != random:
        print "Unfortunately you didn't find it  .. "
if guess == random:
        print "Unbelievable ! You found it .. ! " 
        energy = False
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: You could spell [*"randint"*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) correctly...

Comment: You fixed the code in the question ("randit" to "randint"), so the code no longer has an error.  Which means this question is no longer useful.

Comment: Please see my answer, _randint_ is not the only problem here. It is actually a really relevant question that can happen to a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your files name are not random.py since python interprets this as a module.

**EDIT**

change your variable named `random` to something else. Like so,

```
import random
print ("Try to find the number I have on my mind in once !! ")
print ("Everytime you are wrong the number will change !! ")
guess = 0 
energy = True 
while energy == True:
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    guess = input("What's the number ?? : ")
    if guess != number:
        print ("Unfortunately you didn't find it  .. ")
if guess == number:
        print ("Unbelievable ! You found it .. ! ") 
        energy = False
```

Comment: It is not, It's named test4.py

Comment: Do you have another `random.py` somewhere ?

Comment: No, I do not...

Comment: But you know, I can say you helped me. I solved the problem by changing the name of the variable "random". So it is like number = random.randint. and It works fine !

Comment: @KostasPetrakis see edited answer for the same as before

Comment: @KostasPetrakis this is exactly what I proposed you ahah

Answer (score 0):

It is `randint`, not randit. That's why python is unable to find it.

Update:
You are doing 
`random = random.randit(1,100)`

that is you are overriding the imported random with your random variable. Name it something other than a python keyword/module/function name.
For example: `random_val = random.randint(1, 100)`

Comment: I fixed that, but it keeps displaying the same error .. My code right now looks like this : import random
print "Try to find the number I have on my mind in once !! " 
print "Everytime you are wrong the number will change !! " 
guess = 0 
energy = True 
while energy == True:
 random = random.randint(1,100)
 guess = input("What's the number ?? : ")
 if guess != random:
  print "Unfortunately you didn't find it  .. "
 if guess == random:
  print "Unbelievable ! You found it .. ! " 
  energy = False